# Get count every X second loading more than 1 billion XHR request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use `setInterval` to get my notification counter every `5 second`, I thinks it's bad idea to getting those results. because if you stay on my site for a while you got a billion times of loading XHR loading.
And if you use the facebook, you don't get lot of XHR.
Here is my web site capture XHR:
[image]

My Code in file: `notification.php`:

```
function getnotificount(){
$.post('getnotificount.php', function(data) {
        $('#notifi_count').html(data); 
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
     getnotificount();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Frankly, I am not really sure what your question is. Maybe you should write more structured about what you ultimately want to achieve, how your proposed solution tries to address that, and what problems you see with this solution. The only reasonable interpretation I can think of is that you want to count XHR's at server side and then display that count on your web page every 5 seconds but I am still not sure if that is what you meant because you write it is site-dependent which it wouldn't be if it is the server count etc.

Comment: exactly, I want to want to get XHR's at server side and then display that count on my web page every 5 seconds.

Comment: at 1 XHR every five seconds it would take about 185 years to get `billion times of loading XHR` - so, I think you are perhaps exaggerating a lot

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ok. It is not 'loading more than 1 billion XHR request', it's starting (and finishing - as we can see) a request every X seconds and there's nothing wrong with that.

However it's not the best way to implement a push notification system. That would be [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), which is a way for your client to 'listen' to messages from your server. There are frameworks for this, the most popular one (and the one that I recommend) being [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Your third and most advanced/modern solution would be implementing a [service-worker-based notification system](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/) but I'm pretty sure that's way too complex and not suitable for you since you can't even understand your problem enough to describe it.

Comment: Sir, you're right about my experience, hover, can you tell me what should I do to call my file every x second? without js.node. because you know some of web hosting didn't allow to use node.js. I want to get me a simple example code with you. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is polling, which is making a new request to the server on a regular bases. For a http request, a TCP connection is opened, request / response are exchanged and the TCP connection closed. This is what happens every 5s in your case.

If you want a more light weight solution, have a look at websockets such as [socket.io](https://socket.io/). Only one TCP connection is opened and maintained between the front and the back. This bidirectional conection enables the back to notify the front when something happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad idea at all. It is called polling and it is used at many places as a means to get regularly data from the server. However, it is not the best, nor the most modern solution to do this. In fact, if your server supports [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), then you should use them. You do not need to use NodeJS to use WebSockets, since WebSocket is a protocol of creating a duplex channel of communication between your server and the client. You should read about WebSockets. Also, you can use push notification, which is inferior to WebSockets in my opinion. And a hacky way is to use a forever frame.